# "I loved you to be happy." "I owed you to do it."

Tags: sentence-meaning

> I loved you to be happy.

What does it mean:

1. I loved you because I wanted to be happy
2. I loved you because I wanted you to be happy
3. I loved you because you were happy.

Another one:

> I owed you to do it.

1. I owed you because I wanted you to do it
2. I owed you because I wanted to do it

Which one is correct?

Comment: Are these expressions that you made up, or did you hear/read them somewhere?

Comment: I made up. I was thinking about sentences which pronouns take part as object in, I noticed that.

Answer (score 1):

They are very unlikely sentences.  The meaning is probably ambiguous.  In practical terms you would consider the context to infer the meaning, but the possible meanings are all rather odd.

"I love you to be happy"  could either mean  "I love you in order to be happy" (the infinitive giving the purpose.  Or it could mean something like "I love the process of you becoming happy".
Putting these in the past tense puts the love in the past but doesn't change the meanings.  The first meaning is particularly oxymoronic (love isn't selfish?). The second could be better expressed as "I loved making you happy" or similar.

The second is also odd.  I'd understand it as being like "I owed you £10". So the object is the thing that is owed.  "You don't need to pay me.  I owed you to babysit, because you watched my children last month."  But the syntax isn't quite right and it should probably be expressed with a real noun, or nothing at all.